# Tilemill Error - Zoom level 16

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, tilemill

I am having an error in tilemill with postgresql and the Openstreetmap-carto style that I am having trouble figureing out the reason for. Everything is working perfectly up until I reach zoom level 16. When tilemill is zoomed to level 16 I am receiving this error.
[image: TilemillError]

I am not sure what the cause of it is, or why it is trying to find that attribute when it reaches zoom 16 and not at any other level. The reason this is an issue is I was looking to export the mbtiles at level 17.
I attached the mml code below.

http://pastebin.com/x7Sn0ks5

Comment: Possibly there is a scale-dependent rule that is triggered at zoom level 16. Have you made any changes at all to the style?

Comment: The only changes I made were to the water-features.mss because it was indicating there were some required styles missing. I was looking for something related to that shapefile and zoom level 16 but I have not found anything

Answer (score 1):

Undo your changes and re-run the get-shapefiles.sh script. Downloading a fresh copy of the style is best.

OpenStreetMap Carto is used with Tilemill regularly, so it should work out of the box without any changes. If it doesn't, something went wrong, either with the style or how you set it up to work with Tilemill. To debug this, you need to work with an unmodified copy.

Comment: I have done what you said, now I am getting this error. So frustrating! http://pastebin.com/KhNYaVpk: Still only at level 16 and above